# bxslider does not wait for images in chrome; jumps to last slide

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bxslider

If you go to http://sandkasse.shoporama.dk/, you will see a bxslide at the top of the page. at least, you will if you do not use chrome (Peculiarly, the problem seems not to occur in safari, IE or firefox).

I am experiencing the problem that quite often when loading the page from chrome, the images to be used in the bxslider do no load. refreshing usually solves the problem. All I get is the two buttons for switching slides, however nothing happens when these are clicked.

I don't get any error messages.

I am assuming that the problem is that the images have not finished loading when the      $('.bxslider').bxSlider(); is called inside the  $(document).ready(function(){}).
 However, what is a good fix to this? if I move the bxslider call to window.load, I get the somewhat ugly result that all the images in the slide are shown until the whole page has finished loading, with the wrong width and styling. I suppose I could change the visibility and styling of all the images until the page finishes loading, but this seems more like a hack than a solution?

would it be a sensible choice to use some sort of imagesloaded event instead of document.ready? the imagesloaded package is included anyway. but, I suspect I would run into the same problem of all images showing until the last had loaded?

A related problem may be the fact that the slider always skips to the last slide when the page is loaded, irrespective of which browser is used. I have "fixed" this by setting the "startSlide" manually.

I hope my question makes sense. I am aware that there are a lot of bxslider questions on here, but I haven't been able to find anyone solving this particular problem, except for people "giving up" and resorting to just hiding the images while things load?

Answer (score 0):

I may have come up with a suitably non-hacky solution:

reload the slider in the window.load call. Thus, my bxslider call has transformed into:

```
var slider; // has to be defined beforehand so I can use it in window.load
$(document).ready(function(){
//initialize slider
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
 startSlide:0
});
};)

$(window).load(function() {
  slider.reloadSlider();

 });
```